# In ES6, does Array's find method perform a linear search?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, find

I need to perform a linear search on an array of numbers. If I use find(), will I be guaranteed a linear search from index 0, onward?

I realize I can simply use a for-loop, but would like to use something more elegant.

Comment: Often the documentation will answer questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The [specification states:](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.find)

> find calls predicate once for each element of the array, in ascending order, until it finds one where predicate returns true

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it always starts at index 0, incrementing by 1 each iteration, and returns the first element which matches the criteria. For example:

```js
const arr = [{ id: 1, name: 'a' }, { id: 2, name: 'b' }, { id: 1, name: 'c' }];

console.log(
  arr.find(obj => obj.id === 1)
);
```

The details of the required implementation of `Array.prototype.find` is described [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.find):

> 7. Let k be 0.
> 8. Repeat, while k < len:
>
>    a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
>
>    b. Let kValue be Get(O, Pk).
>
>    c. ReturnIfAbrupt(kValue).
>
>    d. Let testResult be ToBoolean(Call(predicate, T, «kValue, k, O»)).
>
>    e. ReturnIfAbrupt(testResult).
>
>    f. If testResult is true, return kValue.
>
>    g. Increase k by 1.
> 9. Return undefined.

As you can see, it increments `k` by 1 each iteration, checking whether the test passes for each value and `return`ing if so, just like a `for` loop could do with `break`.